# Coordenadas GPS realizar solicitud cuando esta cambia

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una app para que coja las coordenadas GPS cada vez que esta cambia.
Los permisos ya lo he realizado y solo me falta que me funcione cuando las coordenadas cambien.

Atraves de la documentacion he realizado esto, pero aunque cambie solo me da la ultima o la que esta en ese momento pero solo una y la documentacion no me queda muy claro hacerlo cuando cambie las coordenadas.

```
 private void transmitirgps() {
    aux_conesion = 2;
    transmitirbutton.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    stopbutton.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );


    // Ultima localizacion
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient( this );
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener( this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                longuitud.setText( String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) );
                latitud.setText( String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) );
            }
        }
    } );



}
```

Comment: hay un [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/while-in-use-location) que precisamente explica como hacer esto

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer una clase que implemente un LocationListener, esta interface tiene un método llamado

```
onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

Y aquí(en la implementación de ese método) es donde manejarías lo que pasa cuando cambia de localización.